# Openshot trouble, help

Tags: 3d, video-editor, blender, openshot

I installed openshot today and so far I was doing kinda fine but when I went back to create a title(animated) it wont let me progress. I checked blender also it's there but I am helpless and unable to understand what seems to be the problem.

I am posting a screenshot so you guys can see what kinda error am getting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I searched and found this, hope this helps

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sw4n6PL9258

This was uploaded by Ryan D - profile link https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLxlPxUjBipRET4vODsim6Q